# Edge's OverrideSecurityRestrictionsOnInsecureOrigin does not support IntranetFileLinksEnabled?

Tags: microsoft-edge

I want to set [OverrideSecurityRestrictionsOnInsecureOrigin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#overridesecurityrestrictionsoninsecureorigin) in Edge to open file explorer on http sites, but even with internet options (intranet settings) and [IntranetFileLinksEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#intranetfilelinksenabled) set, I can't open file explorer.

The https site can open a file explorer.

Does [OverrideSecurityRestrictionsOnInsecureOrigin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#overridesecurityrestrictionsoninsecureorigin) not support [IntranetFileLinksEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#intranetfilelinksenabled)?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid so. I am also able to reproduce this issue when I enable both **IntranetFileLinksEnabled** and **OverrideSecurityRestrictionsOnInsecureOrigin**. The https site can open the file explorer while the "seemingly secure" http site is unable to open the file explorer.

Since the Dev Team has only mentioned "HTTPS websites are allowed", then it seems that converted http sites via **OverrideSecurityRestrictionsOnInsecureOrigin** will not be recognized in this case.

Comment: Thank you for verifying!
Hopefully the Edge team will address it eventually.